# FS10N, how to choose layout by name with script in excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I'm writing a code in Excel VBA to automatically download data from SAP FS10N report.
The only problem I have right now is that I can't find any solution to select the layout I wan't to use by the name of the layout. This is the code line I found to be the solution but it doesn't work for me:

```
Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ssubD0500_SUBSCREEN:SAPLSLVC_DIALOG:0501/cntlG51_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell")
```

### Any idea how to move on?

Edit:
This is the part of my code where I can't access the pop up window which shows the available layouts. And so I can't select any layout by it's name, only the way the script recorder saved the way I did it manually:

```
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[33]").press
session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 81
session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 81
session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 81
session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 81
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/lbl[1,12]").setFocus
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/lbl[1,12]").caretPosition = 3
session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 2
```

### The repeating lines 2-5 show where I was scrolling up the list.

Edit2:
This is what my script looks like when recorded:

```
If Not IsObject(application) Then
   Set SapGuiAuto  = GetObject("SAPGUI")
   Set application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(connection) Then
   Set connection = application.Children(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(session) Then
   Set session    = connection.Children(0)
End If
If IsObject(WScript) Then
   WScript.ConnectObject session,     "on"
   WScript.ConnectObject application, "on"
End If
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").text = "fs10n"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtSO_SAKNR-LOW").text = "884050"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtGP_GJAHR").text = "2020"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtGP_GJAHR").setFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtGP_GJAHR").caretPosition = 4
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlFDBL_BALANCE_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").setCurrentCell 1,"BALANCE"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlFDBL_BALANCE_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").selectedRows = "1"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlFDBL_BALANCE_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").doubleClickCurrentCell
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[33]").press

'My problem starts here

session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 81
session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 81
session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 81
session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 81
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/lbl[1,12]").setFocus
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/lbl[1,12]").caretPosition = 2
session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 2
```

I wan't somehow replace the last seven lines. I wan't to somehow select a layout by it's name in the dialog box. I hope this is more clear now.

Edit3:
The line above my comment:
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgWJH.png)/btn[33]").press
Opens the layout select dialog box:
[image: FS10N G/L Account Line Item Display]

After clicking the button, this dialog box opens:
[image: ALV layout selection screen as ABAP List rendering]

The last 7 lines of the code are my manual steps scrolling up 4 times, and selecting the wanted layout. Recorder doesn't help me identify the dialog box.

Comment: SAP APPL is 618, and SAP BASIS is 750. I will again edit my question above. Recording does contain selecting a layout in the last 8 rows.

Comment: I've also deleted my comments as they do not add value to resolve the issue. So far I was only read-only mode here at StackOverflow which helped me a lot. However asking the good question short and organised is harder than I thought. In the future I will try my best. Thanks in advance Sandra!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the ALV Layout Selection Screen, if you know the name of the layout you want to select, do this sequence of actions:

1. Given the initial list of layouts, click the button Find:

   [image: ALV Layout Selection Screen - List]
2. Enter the name of the layout, deselect the checkbox "Starting at current line" to search all lines, and press Enter :

   [image: ALV Layout Selection Screen - Find input]
3. The result should show the layout always at the first row, click it:

   [image: ALV Layout Selection Screen - Find results]
4. The list of all layouts should be scrolled at the right line and the cursor is at the right position, press the key `F2`:

   [image: ALV Layout Selection Screen - List with cursor on result]

All the actions above correspond to the following code (as returned by the Script Recorder):

```
session.findById("wnd[0]").resizeWorkingPane 158,25,false
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[33]").press
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[71]").press
session.findById("wnd[2]/usr/chkSCAN_STRING-START").selected = false
session.findById("wnd[2]/usr/txtRSYSF-STRING").text = "/SAP-GLVIEW"
session.findById("wnd[2]/usr/chkSCAN_STRING-START").setFocus
session.findById("wnd[2]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
session.findById("wnd[3]/usr/lbl[1,2]").setFocus
session.findById("wnd[3]/usr/lbl[1,2]").caretPosition = 0
session.findById("wnd[3]").sendVKey 2
session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 2
```

Comment: Dear Sandra! Thanks a lot for your patience and help. This works fine. Not exactly how I thought this could be done, but anyhow the result is great. Thanks again! ;)